# Font and style in Table of Contents

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, templates, front-matter, roman-numerals

[image]

I am using a template for my thesis (Thesis - University of Bergen - Masters thesis pre-template (Infomedia)), and there is a problem with the style of the contents. The number to the far right is in a different font than all the other. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Although the problem is evident in the image you show, it will be much easier for potential helpers if you provide code for a brief example that demonstrates the problem, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The page numbers are in the same font as the entries. Bold for bold entries (e.g., Abstract), regular for regular entries (e.g., Motivation). This is the standard format for the ToC and friends.

Comment: @PeterWilson Not all of it. The page numbers for the sections are clearly in a sans serif font like Helvetica. The [template is available on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/masters-thesis-pre-template-infomedia-for-university-of-bergen/xzwdyfrytxpw), but I don't have an Overleaf account and the "View Source" shows code that can't be compiled as is, but I'll keep investigating a bit.

Comment: Ugh, that template is a *mess*. Natbib is loaded more than once. The `\author` command is inside the `\title` command, and the `\date` command is inside that! But the problem seems to be the line right before front matter that reads `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %KD`. Not sure why that's there, since the template clearly isn't mean to use sans by default. but try just removing it and let us know if that works. Again, I can't test it.

Comment: @frabjous That worked, thanks! I will try to clean up the other issues with the template too.

Comment: @frabjous If the numbers are in a sans serif font then that is to do with the template. I tried accessing the template but with no luck. Either the OP should accept what the template provides or complain to the template's author.